# cannot plot a line graph in R using plot(), other graph types will work

Tags: r, plot, graph

I am trying to plot a line graph in R using the plot() function, however the plot pane is remaining blank. When I try to plot it is a point, bar, histogram etc the plot can be seen in the plots pane. I have also not been able to add any information using the line() command. Any ideas?

This doesn't work:

```
plot(GPSPlayerZ$GPSTime, GPSPlayerZ$SpeedDoppler, type = "l")
lines(GPSPlayerZ$GPSTime, GPSPlayerZ$SpeedDopplerSmooth, col = "blue")
```

This does:

```
plot(GPSPlayerZ$GPSTime, GPSPlayerZ$SpeedDoppler, type = "h")
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT

```
structure(list(GPSTime = c(43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43498.69211, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43498.69211, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43498.69212, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Latitude = c(53.33522783, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53.33522783, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 53.33522783, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
53.33522783, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53.33522783, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53.33522783, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53.335228, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 53.33522817, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53.33522833, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53.3352285, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Longitude = c(-6.22882633, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.228826, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, -6.22882583, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.22882567, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.22882517, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.228825, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, -6.22882483, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.22882467, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.2288245, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -6.2288245, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), SpeedDoppler = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), HeartRate = c(45, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 45, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
45, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 45, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), LateralAccelerometry = c(0, -0.0125, -0.0125, -0.0125, 
-0.025, -0.025, -0.025, -0.0375, -0.0375, -0.025, -0.0125, 0, 
0, -0.0125, -0.025, -0.025, -0.0125, -0.0125, -0.0125, 0, 0, 
0, 0.0125, 0.0125, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.0375, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 
0.025, 0, 0, -0.0125, 0, 0, 0, -0.0125, -0.0125, -0.0125, -0.025, 
-0.05, -0.0625, -0.0625, -0.05, -0.05, -0.0375, -0.025, -0.025, 
-0.025, -0.025, -0.0625, -0.0875, -0.1125, -0.1375, -0.1375, 
-0.125, -0.125, -0.1125, -0.1125, -0.1125, -0.1, -0.0875, -0.075, 
-0.075, -0.1, -0.1125, -0.1125, -0.1125, -0.1125, -0.125, -0.1125, 
-0.1125, -0.1, -0.0875, -0.0875, -0.0875, -0.075, -0.075, -0.0625, 
-0.075, -0.0625, -0.0625, -0.075, -0.075, -0.0625, -0.0625, -0.05, 
-0.0375, -0.05, -0.0375), ForwardAccelerometry = c(0.5125, 0.5125, 
0.5125, 0.5125, 0.5125, 0.5125, 0.5125, 0.5125, 0.5125, 0.5125, 
0.525, 0.5125, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 
0.525, 0.5375, 0.5375, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.5375, 0.5375, 
0.5375, 0.5375, 0.5125, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 0.525, 
0.525, 0.5375, 0.5375, 0.5375, 0.5375, 0.525, 0.5125, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5125, 0.5125, 0.5, 0.475, 0.475, 0.475, 0.475, 0.475, 
0.4875, 0.5125, 0.5375, 0.5375, 0.5375, 0.4875, 0.475, 0.5, 0.5125, 
0.5375, 0.55, 0.5625, 0.575, 0.5875, 0.575, 0.5625, 0.575, 0.5875, 
0.575, 0.575, 0.575, 0.5875, 0.6, 0.6, 0.575, 0.5625, 0.575, 
0.5625, 0.575, 0.5875, 0.5875, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6125, 0.6375, 
0.6375, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625, 0.625
), UpAccelerometry = c(0.975, 0.9625, 0.9625, 0.975, 0.975, 0.9625, 
0.9625, 0.9625, 0.95, 0.9625, 0.9625, 0.975, 0.975, 0.975, 0.9625, 
0.9625, 0.9625, 0.9625, 0.95, 0.9625, 0.9625, 0.9625, 0.9625, 
0.9625, 0.9625, 0.9625, 0.9625, 0.9625, 0.9625, 0.9625, 0.95, 
0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.9375, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.9625, 
0.9625, 0.975, 0.975, 0.9875, 0.975, 0.9875, 0.9875, 1, 1, 0.9875, 
0.9875, 0.975, 0.975, 0.9875, 1, 1.0125, 1.0125, 1, 1, 0.975, 
0.975, 0.9875, 0.975, 0.9625, 0.95, 0.9625, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 
0.9125, 0.9125, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9125, 0.925, 0.925, 0.9375, 0.925, 
0.9125, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8875, 0.8875, 0.8875, 
0.8875, 0.8875, 0.8875, 0.8875, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9125, 0.9125, 0.9125, 
0.925, 0.925), SpeedDopplerSmooth = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Accel = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of your data? Copy the output of `dput(GPSPlayerZ[1:100,])`

Comment: Hey @Edward, not sure if this helps? It won't let me post it all.
I managed to do a line graph with a similar data set
> dput(GPSPlayerZ[1:100,])
structure(list(GPSTime = c(43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43498.69211, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
43498.69211, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43498.69211,

Comment: you should put it in the question. Not in a comment

Comment: Are the `NA` expected? Maybe there is an issue with importing the data...

Comment: The NA was expected as there were multiple blank cells in the data I was given to import. I added na.omit my data import and that fixed many of my issues :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `NA` values in your data.  Each line 'segment' is only a single point, because the next point is `NA`.  A line segment from a given point to `NA` cannot be drawn.

For example

```
df1 = data.frame(x=c(1,NA,2,NA,3), y=c(1,NA,2,NA,3))

plot(df1)
```

[image]

```
plot(df1, type='l')
```

[image]

Try removing the NA values first

```
plot(df1[complete.cases(df1),], type='l')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! sorry for a potentially, silly question, but is there a way to remove those NAs if i've imported the data from a csv file rather then writing a dataset? is the best way to fill the blanks with a '0', for example, in the original data?

Comment: You can use `complete.cases`, as in my example

Comment: amazing, got it working! thanks so much for your help!